# skimage mean is not returning expected result?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have the following code:

Shouldn't the center entry in the result(at index [1,1]) be `(2+4+5+5+7)/9 = int(2.55) = 2`?

I am imagining that the following happens when viewed as a convolution:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.filters.rank import mean
from skimage.morphology import disk
A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print("A: {}".format(A))
print("disk(1): {}".format(disk(1)))
print("mean: {}".format(mean(A, disk(1))))
```

Our kernel is `K = 1/9(disk(1))` and the input image is `A`, resulting in the convolution(with arrays seen as discrete functions): `A * K`. Hence, I would expect that the center pixel in `A` would be turned into `(2+4+5+5+7)/9 = int(2.55) = 2` by the definition of convolutions. Why is this not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skimage.filters.rank.mean` computes the mean over the pixels with value 1 in the selection element rather than over the entire window. If you pass in `disk(1)` as the selection element, then the neighbourhood is formed by just 5 pixels, not 9. Hence, the normalising factor for the convolution kernel should be 1/5 instead of 1/9.

#### Demo

```py
In [77]: import numpy as np
    ...: from skimage.filters.rank import mean
    ...: from skimage.morphology import disk
    ...: from scipy.signal import convolve2d

In [78]: A = np.arange(1, 17).reshape(4, 4)

In [79]: A
Out[79]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])

In [80]: d = disk(1)

In [81]: d
Out[81]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)

In [82]: mean(A, d)[1:-1, 1:-1]
Out[82]: 
array([[ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]], dtype=uint8)

In [83]: convolve2d(A, d, mode='valid')/d.sum()
Out[83]: 
array([[ 6.,  7.],
       [10., 11.]])
```

Notice that in the code above only valid pixels are considered, i.e. those pixels for which the selection element is fully contained within the image.

Comment: You have no idea how much I appreciate this. May you have a wonderful day!